# Outlook 2007 DASL query tasks

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, task

I'm going crazy on this one.
Basically I want to retrieve a task based on the EntryID of this task.
so what I do is the following:

Outlook.MAPIFolder outlookTasksFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
string filter = String.Format("@SQL=\"urn:schemas:tasks:entryid\" like '%{0}%'", myEntryID); 
Outlook.Items outlookTasksDataItems = outlookTasksFolder.Restrict(filter);

but i does not work.
I don't know how to format my query to get the corresponding items (there should be only one really).

can anyone please help me?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook.MAPIFolder outlookTasksFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);

Outlook.TaskItem myOutlookTask = (Outlook.TaskItem)Application.Session.GetItemFromID(myEntryID, outlookTasksFolder.EntryId);

That should do it.

Comment: that's what i finally did.
and it worked fine.
thank you very much.